# Meaning of “vu et archirevu”

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, préfixes

What does "vu et archirevu" mean? I'm guessing it's something like "seen and seen over" or "been there, done that" but I cannot find "archirevu" in any dictionary. Here's an example:

> L'Italie et ses beautés, vu et archirevu.

Source: [Le Point – Publié le 16/06/2011 à 10:25](http://www.lepoint.fr/salon-du-bourget-2011/embarquement-pour-l-espace-16-06-2011-1342600_375.php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*archi-* is a prefix used to indicate something pushed to its limits, going further the usual meaning.

Its use is rather colloquial today, but it still remains in some words, mainly in religious/noble titles : *archevêque* (archbishop), *archiduc* (archduke), *archiprêtre* (archpriest)...

In your context, *archirevu* would mean exactly what you guessed, *seen again and again*. Some other common colloquial uses are *archicomble* / *archiplein* (meaning a place is full over the top), *archifaux* (something totally wrong), *archiconnu* (extremely well-known)

Comment: I would add that “*vu et revu*” is somewhat idiomatic (meaning “seen many times”). “*vu et archirevu*” is an intensifier on that.

Answer (score 1):

It is a repetition. It means "*again and again*". Your sentence could be translated like this :

> Italy and all its beauties, seen again and again.

Moreover it is normal that you do not find "*archirevu*" because it is not one word but two. It is not "*archirevu*" (which does not exist in French) but "*archi revu*".